# Standard errors of each observation among grouped data in data frame

Tags: r, grouping, dataframe, tapply

I have a data frame where I'd like to calculate the standard error of observations grouped by factors in three columns. The standard deviation and standard error of the mean of the groups have been calculated like this, using tapply:

```
aveResponse <- tapply(df$Response, col1:col2:col3, mean, na.rm=T)

aveSD <- tapply(df$Response, col1:col2:col3, sd, na.rm=T)

stderr <- function(x) sqrt(var(x,na.rm=TRUE)/(length(na.omit(x)))
aveSEM <- tapply(df$Response, col1:col2:col3, stderr, na.rm=T)
```

I have earlier calculated the standard deviation for the individual observations (saved in column colSD) and would like to calculate the corresponding standard errors. Using the function below, I'm able to get the standard errors:

```
stderr <- function(x) x/sqrt(length(na.omit(x)))
SEM<- tapply(df$colSD, col1:col2:col3, stderr)
```

But, the results are given as an array, with the n observations from each group as a string (I think) in each position. Any ideas how to move further, either by changing the function, using another function or converting the array to a vector where the standard error from each observation has its own position?

A small sample (is it easier for you to work with if I past the dput(df)?):

```
>df
    col1    col2  col3 Response colSD
1  food1 tissue1 gene1    1.644 0.080
2  food1 tissue1 gene1    1.726 0.093
3  food1 tissue2 gene1    0.088 0.014
4  food1 tissue2 gene1    0.002 0.000
5  food2 tissue1 gene1    0.311 0.012
6  food2 tissue1 gene1    0.657 0.265
7  food2 tissue2 gene1    0.000 0.000
8  food2 tissue2 gene1    0.001 0.000
9  food1 tissue1 gene2    3.223 0.246
10 food1 tissue1 gene2    2.156 0.440
11 food1 tissue2 gene2    0.279 0.200
12 food1 tissue2 gene2    0.033 0.007
13 food2 tissue1 gene2    0.044 0.002
14 food2 tissue1 gene2    0.265 0.117
15 food2 tissue2 gene2    0.000 0.000
16 food2 tissue2 gene2    0.000 0.000
```

I would like to calculate the standard error for each observation such as `0.080/sqrt(2)`, `0.093/sqrt(2)` and so on, and add the results to the data frame as an additional column:

```
>df
    col1    col2  col3 Response colSD colSEM
1  food1 tissue1 gene1    1.644 0.080  0.057
2  food1 tissue1 gene1    1.726 0.093  0.066 etc...
```

Comment: It would be great if you could give us a small sample dataset of `df`, and you explained what you wanted the data to look like in the end. Try using `dput(df)` so we can cut and paste easily, or just use `dput(head(df))` if `df` is too big.

Comment: Do not change the question to a followup problem once an answer to the original problem has been given. I rolled back your edit to restore the original meaning of the question. Otherwise the answers would not apply. Please either *add* small follow-up questions without removing the original question, or post a completely *new question*, perhaps giving a link to in a comment here to keep the same set of people interested. Which one is appropriate depends on the scope of the follow-up problem, and the degree of interrelation, but in this case probably the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a very compact solution using `ddply`:

```
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(df, .(col1, col2, col3), transform, colSEM = colSD/sqrt(length(na.omit(colSD))))
```

For those interested in how this solution evolved, have a look at the edit history.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! I do have a follow-up question though, regarding the ordering of the rows when making a data frame with the averages, sd and sem of the averages. Please se above.

Comment: @user1214160, here is an even shorter version than the one before my most recent edit.